# Using pointers to change the bytes of integer variable

Tags: c, pointers

So I am currently trying to teach myself C and am currently a little bit stuck in a exercise about pointers. So the task is to have three variables (char, char, short) which stand for the day, month and year of a certain date. I am asked to then use pointers to save these three variables into one. I thought it would make sense to store it on the different bytes of the variable since we are just using char and short. Now I tried to use pointers to put for example the value of the day into the first byte of the integer.

I have come to two problems that I cannot figure out the solution for:

1. `warning: assignment to 'char *' from incompatible pointer type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] daypointer = (&date);`

So I think this means, that I try to use a pointer for a type that it is not meant to point on. I am not sure if I understand it right so please correct me if I'm wrong. I also don't understand how I can fix this since the exercise asked for char, char and unsigned variables and not integers.

```
 a2.c:60:11: error: 'date' undeclared (first use in this function)
   60 |     month(date);
```

So I tried to use the returned value date from the first function to call the other functions and don't know why this doesn't work.

For reference, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//uses pointers to store the three variables into one integer variable
int create_date (unsigned char day, unsigned char month, unsigned short year){
    char *daypointer;
    char *monthpointer;
    int *yearpointer;
    int date = 0;

    daypointer = (&date);
    *daypointer = day;

    monthpointer = (&date+1);
    *monthpointer = month;

    yearpointer = (&date+2);
    *yearpointer = year;

    return date;
}


//return day, month or year of the date
int year (int date){
    int *pointer;
    unsigned short year;

    pointer = (&date+2);
    *pointer = year;

    printf("Year:%d", year);
}

int month (int date){
    char *pointer;
    unsigned char month;

    pointer = (&date+1);
    *pointer = month;

    printf("Month:%c", month);
}

int day (int date){
    char *pointer;
    unsigned char day;

    pointer = (&date);
    *pointer = day;

    printf("Day:%c", day);
}

int main(void){
    //int date = 0;

    create_date(11, 12, 2020);

    month(date);
    day(date);
    year(date);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me understanding my mistakes a little. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you have got some assignment which instructs you to pack the values of day, month, and year into a four-byte `int`. To do this, yes, you have to explicitly tell the compiler you are converting a pointer to an `int` to a pointer to a `char`.

But first, the error you are getting on line 60 is because there is no `date` declared in `main`. Why is your line `//int date = 0;` commented out?

Further, it is not clear why you have some many subroutines or how your program is supposed to be structured. Maybe the assignment you were given gives particular instructions about this, but you have not shown us the details of the assignment, so we do not know. In any case, you should perhaps just get the “pack the bytes into the `int`” operations working, and then you can add more code for the rest of the assignment.

You can start with `int date;`. We will assume `int` is four bytes.

Then you can make a pointer to its first byte with `char *p = (char *) &date;`.

Then you can write a day of the month to its first byte with `p[0] = 13;`, and you can write a month to its second byte with `p[1] = 6;`.

To write a year to the last two bytes is more complicated. Options include:

- Decompose the year and write the two bytes separately: `short year = 2020; p[2] = year / 256; p[3] = year % 256;`.
- Make a pointer to `short` and use that: `short *q = (short *) (p+2); *q = 2020;`.
- Copy into the bytes using `memcpy`: `short year = 2020; memcpy(p+2, year, sizeof year);`.

You should not use the second option, because it has semantic problems regarding the rules of C. The other two options are supported by the C standard but they have different effects regarding the order in which bytes are stored in memory. The second one will generally match what your C implementation uses, so it may be the one your assignment intends.

Comment: I commented l.60 out, because I thought then it would give me the date of 0. Which would then be month 0, day 0 and year 0. I thought I can comment it out because the create_date returns the variable date.                                                                                                Thank you for explaining step by step what my mistakes are because pointers are just something that feels so counterintuitive to me. I think I can now try to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have so many errors here - it is even hard to explain them. I advise starting from something easier than the pointers, as you do not know anything about the assignments, parameters, functions, variables and other basic C stuff.

Abstracting, pointer punning is generally dangerous, invokes many effects which may lead to UBs and it is difficult to understand by beginners.

I have modified your code to work on modern systems where little endian order is used.

```
unsigned create_date (unsigned char day, unsigned char month, unsigned short year){
    
    return day | ((unsigned)month << 8) | ((unsigned)year << 16);
}


//return day, month or year of the date
unsigned short year (unsigned date){
    unsigned short *pointer;

    pointer = (unsigned short *)(((char *)&date) + 2);

    printf("Year:%hd", *pointer);
    return *pointer;
}

int month (unsigned date){
    char *pointer = (char *)&date;

    printf("Month:%hhd", *(pointer+1));
    return *(pointer+1);
}

int day (unsigned date){
    char *pointer;
    pointer = (char *)&date;

    printf("Day:%hhd", *pointer);
    return *pointer;
}

int main(void){
    unsigned date;

    date = create_date(11, 12, 2020);

    month(date);
    day(date);
    year(date);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Could you please explain what this line means: return day | ((unsigned)month << 8) | ((unsigned)year << 16);? So do you shift the bits by 8 or 16?

Comment: it sets day on byte 0, month on byte 1 and year on bytes 2 & 3